# Write the smallest positive number that can be represented by the floating point system

Tags: floating-point

Using a normalised floating point representation box with an 8-bit mantissa and a 4-bit exponent, both stored using two’s complement.

(a) Write the smallest positive number that can be represented by the floating point system in the boxes below. The result is:
 Mantissa 0.1000000 and exponent 1000

Do not see how this can could someone please explain.

Comment: We're not looking for posts that simply copy the text of an exercise-style task and ask us to solve it for you.  You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  Make sure to credit the original source of all copied material.

Answer (score 1):

It is 0.100000, because normalised values are only allowed to start with 01 or 10. The exponent is 1000 (-8 in decimal) because that is the smallest possible value that can be represented using two's compliment in 4 bits. The value of the exponent means that the floating point will be moved 8 values to the left, thus making the result smaller.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the exact details of the floating point representation. Several are possible. Much more detail than you ever wanted to know is available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).